# When i mouseover the same element i want it to get darker - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, mouseover, opacity

I want the div that i hover the mouse over that it gets darker each time i mouseover(like etch-a-sketch), but i have run into the problem of not making the opacity be able to get darker more then once.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < (16 * 16); i++) {
  var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
  iDiv.textContent = "  ";
  iDiv.id = 'block';
  iDiv.className = 'block';
  var container = document.getElementById("container");

  container.appendChild(iDiv);

  iDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    // highlight the mouseover target
    this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    this.style.opacity += 0.2;

    // reset the color after a short delay
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.target.style.color = " ";
    }, 500);
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: repeat(16, 1fr);
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
}

#block {
  background: white;
  padding: 12.5px;
}

#block:hover {
  background: ;
}

.color {
  background: rgba {
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0.1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, `opacity` gets turned into a `string`, so when you add `0.2` instead of getting `0.4` you get `0.20.2`.

You need to `parseFloat` on it first.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < (16*16); i++) {
  const iDiv = document.createElement('div');
  const container = document.getElementById("container");
  iDiv.textContent = "  ";
  iDiv.id = 'block';
  iDiv.className = 'block';

  container.appendChild(iDiv); 

  iDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {   
    // highlight the mouseover target
    this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    this.style.opacity = (parseFloat(this.style.opacity) || 0) + 0.2;

    // reset the color after a short delay
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "none";
      this.style.opacity = 0;
    }, 5000);
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: repeat(16, 1fr);
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
}

#block{
  background: white;
  padding: 12.5px;
}

#block:hover{
  background:;
}

.color{
  background: rgba{0,0,0,0.1}
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container"></div>
```

As a side note, for your timeout, it wouldn't work because the context of `this` would be lost by the time the `setTimeout()` was called. You need to either `bind()` the function or use an arrow function (like I did). I bumped the timeout to `5000` instead of `500` so you can more easily see the main focus.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and helping me with this.

Comment: @mahdi0123 Of course. If it turns out to be the correct answer for you, be sure to upvote and mark it as the answer. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues.  First you need a variable if you want to reference `this` inside of the `setTimeout`.  Second, the opacity value is saved as a string, so  you have to parse it.

```js
for (var i=0; i<(16*16); i++){
  var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
  iDiv.textContent = "  ";
  iDiv.id = 'block';
  iDiv.className = 'block';
  var container = document.getElementById("container");

  container.appendChild(iDiv); 

  iDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {   
    // highlight the mouseover target
    var that = event.target;
    that.style.backgroundColor = "black";    
    if(parseFloat(that.style.opacity)) {
      that.style.opacity = parseFloat(that.style.opacity) + 0.2;
    } else {
      that.style.opacity = 0.2;
    }

    // reset the color after a short delay
    setTimeout(function() {
      that.style.color = " ";
    }, 500);
  }, false);

 }
```

```css
    .container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: repeat(16, 1fr);
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
}

#block{
  background: white;
  padding: 12.5px;
}

#block:hover{
  background:;
}

.color{
  background: rgba{0,0,0,0.1}
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the time. Appreciate you answering me.